# "correspondence from A to B" or "correspondence between A and B"

Tags: prepositions, usage, mathematics, logic

Usually we are familiar with the usage:

> "correspondence between A and B"

but can we also use:

> "correspondence from A to B" ?

Does the 2nd case grammatically work, too?

Here the correspondence is not specific to the mailing correspondence,  but to the math function or the physical relation.

Comment: *From A to B* would designate only the letters &c which A wrote, not letters written by both A and B.

Comment: I find that the 2nd case is used here: ["In category theory, a correspondence from C to D" in math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_(mathematics)).

Comment: Ah. If you are speaking of mathematical correspondence, ignore my comment. You may have to migrate this question to  [math.SE] if there is no one active here who is familiar with sophisticated mathematical usage.

Comment: What StoneyB said. From [Basic Algebra II: Second Edition](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gives+the+connection+between+the+notation+for+correspondences%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) *"If (I) is a correspondence **from** A to B, the inverse correspondence <I>_1 **from** B to A is the set of pairs (b, a) such that [blah blah]*. That all goes over my head, but obviously it suggests there's a domain-specific usage involved. Usually (and for the purposes of ELL), we speak of *correspondence **between** [two people/things which correspond in some way]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main meanings of correspondence that come to mind:

1. two things exacty lining up
2. messages exchanged between two things

The first case includes things like

- "His rise in blood pressure exactly corresponded to when he eat salty pretzels." (So "there is a correspondence between his rise in blood pressure and when he eats salty pretzels.")
- "The complex numbers correspond to the set of 2x2 real matrices satisfying such and such properties."

And the second

- "The correspondence between Hardy and Ramanujan regarding prime numbers."
- "I received a correspondence from my friend abroad."

These usages somewhat overlap with things like

- "The correspondence from his eating salty foods to his blood pressures can be explained by what salt does to water."

So *from* usually implies messages, but can also refer to a relation.

Comment: @ldear also, see edit.